# apexchart, pie chart ,the fill colors gradient not take effect in last 3 colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, pie-chart, apexcharts

why does the fill colors gradient not take effect in the last 3 colors?

Does anyone know that?

maybe they have to change something on this file

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.35.3/apexcharts.min.js

```js
optionsos = {

    chart: {
        height: 225,
        type: "pie"
    },
    stroke: {
        curve: "smooth",
        width: 0
    },
    series: [30, 15, 25, 18, 20, 13, 15, 10, 23, 25],
    labels: ["Series 1", "Series 2", "Series 3", "Series 4", "Series 5", "Series 6", "Series 7", "Series 8", "Series 9", "Series 10"],
    colors: ["#99b3ff", "#4ca6ff", "#0080ff", "#006cd9", "#00468c", "#6c00d9", "#ffbfff", "#7396ff", "#3600d9", "#ff99ff"],
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        expandOnClick: true,
      }
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'gradient',
      gradient: {
        shade: 'dark',
        type: "horizontal",
        shadeIntensity: 0.5,
        gradientToColors: '#5c26ff',
        inverseColors: true,
        opacityFrom: 1,
        opacityTo: 1,
        stops: [2, 18, 28, 100, 60, 150],
        colorStops: []
      }
    },
    legend: {
        show: !1,
    },
};
chartart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#pie_chart"), optionsos).render();
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-4">
<div class="card text-center" style="max-height: 280px; min-height: 280px;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Top 10</h4>


        <div id="pie_chart" height="300"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</div> 

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.35.3/apexcharts.min.js
"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, the only thing you have to change is the gradientToColors property to an array, in the documentation it appears as array
gradient to colors: matrix

For example, in this case:

```
gradientToColors: [
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000",
        "#000000"
      ],
```

[Codesandbox Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-poincare-q0c50y?file=/src/pieChartGradient.js)

Result of the solution in photo

[image]